# Samsung Galaxy S3 random reboot during clipboard use

Tags: gmail, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, chrome-for-android

I have a UK sim-free Samsung Galaxy S3. It's had official OTA updates only, and is not rooted or modified in any way.  It's running Jelly Bean.

Since getting the Jelly Bean upgrade it's possible to get the phone to reboot by using cut and paste functionality.  I've achieved this with both the Gmail app and Chrome.  I've seen it on other people's phones too.  I've performed a factory reset and the problem continues.

To reproduce, load up Chrome and then long-press on any webpage with text, select a little text, and then either press the highlighted text or the `copy to clipboard` icon (two overlapping rectangles).  After between 1 and 20 attempts, my phone will reboot.  Sometimes it will reboot when I paste something; for example a URL into the URL bar at the top of Chrome's screen.

I've not been able to reproduce this on the stock browser, despite a number of attempts, nor on any other apps (apart from Gmail).

I'd be interested to hear if any other people are affected by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I read your question it sounded like a Chrome bug to me.

I looked around, and YES, it's a bug on Samsung's multi-entry clipboard feature, and it's been [reported here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35732).

Here are two things you can do to fix this:
(1) If your phone is rooted, delete the contents of "/data/clipbord/*".
(2) OR, Do a factory reset.

Comment: factory reset? I would think that's a pretty lame solution... the best the OP can do, is root it and carry out option 1 instead of losing their data and apps... :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Edited my post. Added "OR". :D

Comment: that's cool :) No worries :)

Comment: Has that been fixed yet?