# Disable booting into Safe Mode on damaged S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, root-access, safe-mode

I have a rooted i9300 (Samsung S3) that is damaged, and only boots into safe mode.

You can read about some people with the same problem [HERE](http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-galaxy-s-iii-rooting-roms-hacks/362794-samsung-galaxy-s3-stuck-safe-mode-print.html) and [HERE](http://support.t-mobile.com/message/332674).

Took the device to Samsung Tech Center, they wanted to replace the motherboard. That's 2/3 of the secondhand price of the device. Big NO.

There is also [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34375/galaxy-s3-randomly-booted-into-safe-mode-strange-behavior) that may be related, but to me the why is already settled. Damaged motherboard. Now...

---

After this debrief, Here goes my question:

Is there a way to make the S3 NOT boot into safe mode? Disable booting into safe mode? A ROM that can do that?

I know it sounds stupid, but its better than throwing the device out.

Answer (score 0):

Install the MIUI for S3. I have the same problem with mine. I tried all there is to try and finally this is something which worked for me.

Comment: Instead of only giving an option to install a custom ROM, also explain why that fixes the problem...

Comment: I dont' know why it fixes it, I just know it does.